# Why is this post method not being retrieved?

Tags: javascript, php

Currently working on a messaging system for my site. I've created a JavaScript function to send post data, and a corresponding PHP file to insert the data. However, the data is not being sent to the database. I'm not sure if the error is in the JavaScript or the PHP file as there is no error log being created.

**HTML**:

```
<form action="javascript:sendPM();" name="pmForm" id="pmForm" method="post">
   <input name="pm_send_id" id="pm_send_id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['userID']; ?>" />
   <input name="pm_send_name" id="pm_send_name" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['userName']; ?>" />
   <input name="pm_receive_id" id="pm_receive_id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['userID']; ?>" />
   <input name="pm_receive_name" id="pm_receive_name" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['userName']; ?>" />               
   <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
   <h4>Send to <?php echo $row['userName']; ?></h4>
   <div class="sectionheader"></div>
   <div id="interaction"></div>
   <br>
   <p>Comment:</p>
   <textarea name="pmTextArea" id="pmTextArea"></textarea>
   <p>Select Video:</p>
   <input name="pmSubmit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

**JavaScript**:

```
$('#pmForm').submit(function(){$('input[type=submit]', this).attr('disabled','disabled');});
  function sendPM(){
    var pmTextArea = $("pmTextArea");
    var sendName = $("pm_send_name");
    var sendID = $("pm_send_id");
    var receiveName = $("pm_receive_name");
    var receiveID = $("pm_receive_id");
    var url = "messages.php";
    if (pmTextArea.val() == ""){
      $("#interaction").html('Comment field is empty.').show().fadeOut(5000);
    }
    else {
    $.post(url,{ message: pmTextArea.val(), sendername: sendName.val(), senderid: sendID.val(), recname: receiveName.val(), recID: receiveID.val() },    function(data){
      $("#interaction").html(data).show().fadeOut(5000);
      document.pmForm.pmTextArea value='';
      });
    }
  }
```

**PHP**:

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once 'class.channel.php';
require_once 'dbconfig.php';
$user_message = new USER();

if (isset($_POST['message'])) {
  $to = ($_POST['recID']);
  $from = ($_POST['senderid']);
  $toName = ($_POST['sendername']);
  $fromName = ($_POST['recname']);
  $msg = htmlspecialchars($_POST['message']);

  $stmt = $user_message->runQuery("INSERT INTO inbox(send_id, receive_id, timesent, comment) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)");
  $stmt->bindValue(1,$from);
  $stmt->bindValue(2,$to);
  $stmt->bindValue(3,now());
  $stmt->bindValue(4,$msg);
  $stmt->execute();
}
?>
```

Comment: You have 3 fields in your `INSERT`, but 4 placeholders. Since you have 4 `bindValue()`s, I assume you missed a field in the `INSERT`. Turning error reporting on might help you debug this easily in the future. `error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set("display_errors", 1);`

Comment: I did yes. However, it still doesn't work with changes. No errors are being reported.

Comment: Its your jquery `document.pmForm.pmTextArea value='';` and the selectors are missing `#`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `#` to retrieve value using their `id`, which you are missing.

```
var pmTextArea = $("pmTextArea");
```

should be

```
var pmTextArea = $("#pmTextArea");
```

And yes, you need to correct, which @RyanHame pointed

```
document.pmForm.pmTextArea value='';
```

to

```
document.pmForm.pmTextArea.value='';
```